# Yii2 multidatabase query

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I'm struggling with creating activequery joining data from 2 different databases. 
Both Databases are on same machine, on PostgreSQL.
In one DB i have almost all my data, but two columns - 'name' and 'region_id', which are in second DB. 
I've made relation and i can get these values, but the problem is i need to get values from DB1 depending on region_id from DB2.

DB1(table districts):
district_id -> relation called 'topology' with DB2(id),
some more data...

DB2(table district):
id,
name,
region_id.

I got Two models, to both tables and they works well.
In model for DB1 i got relation to table in DB2 called 'topology', and if i try:`Districts::find()->joinWith('topology')->all();` all i get is DB Exception with message Relation not exists.

**All in need to do is add clause where to get records with only one region_id...**

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Postgres does not support queries between two different databases. You need to put all tables in a *single* database. If you want to separate them, logically use schemas

Answer (score 0):

i think multi database work only for MySQL

for other DB multi database `join` doesn't work

but in Yii2 multidatabase work when you use `relation` If you models using a different databases